# Show that $\sum _{k\in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-πx^{2} k^{2}} =\frac{1}{x}\sum _{k\in \mathbb{Z}} e^{\frac{-πk^{2}}{x^{2}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

While working with some series, I stumbled upon this identity which I cannot prove:

$$\sum _{k\in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-πx^{2} k^{2}} =\frac{1}{x}\sum _{k\in \mathbb{Z}} e^{\frac{-πk^{2}}{x^{2}}}$$

This kind of relation is something I've never seen in a summation, so I don't know where to even start.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula

Comment: Out of curiosity, how'd you stumble across it?

Comment: This formula cannot be true as written I believe. The left hand side is an even function of $x$ and the right is odd. Should there be an absolute value?

Comment: @eepperly16 Yes, there should be an absolute value. My bad.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I was working with the Ramanujan Theta function and trying to prove the integral representation provided on Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_theta_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is called Jacobi's function, use Poisson summation formula (your function satisfies the hypothesis) : $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f(n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\widehat{f}(n)$$
where $$ \widehat{f}(n)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{-2i\pi n x}dx $$